# How to read from CompositeChannelBuffer?

Tags: http, netty

During my testing, I am loading an JPG image from browser with netty based littleproxy sitting between server and client. While loading this particular image. The channel buffer is of CompositChannelBuffer. I am reading the following way, but is not working.

```
if (chanBuff instanceof CompositeChannelBuffer) {

    CompositeChannelBuffer compChanBuf = ((CompositeChannelBuffer) chanBuff);

    int noOfComps = compChanBuf.numComponents();
    List<ChannelBuffer> buffList = compChanBuf.decompose(0, noOfComps);

    ListIterator<ChannelBuffer> itr = buffList.listIterator();
    int offSet = 0;
    int bytesRead = -1;

    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        ChannelBuffer buf = (ChannelBuffer) itr.next();
        bytesRead = buf.array().length;
        outputStream.write(buf.array(), offSet, bytesRead);
        offSet += bytesRead;
    }
}
```

I also tried the below code, but this also not able to write to the file.

```
if (chanBuff instanceof CompositeChannelBuffer){

    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);

    CompositeChannelBuffer compChanBuf = ((CompositeChannelBuffer) chanBuff);
    int noOfComps = compChanBuf.numComponents();

    compChanBuf.getBytes(0, outputStream, noOfComps);

    ChannelBuffer dynamicBuf = dynamicBuffer();
    compChanBuf.getBytes(0, dynamicBuf);
    array = dynamicBuf.array();

    outputStream.write(array);
}
```

What is the correct way to read the CompositChannelBuffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do it like you would do for other buffers like:

```
ChannelBuffer buf = ...
OutputStream out = ...
buf.getBytes(0, out, buf.readableBytes());
```

Comment: Thanks Norman. This worked! In what situation we use decompose then? Just want to understand as I already touched that API, and would be useful to know. Thanks again!

Comment: Most of the times you not need to cast to CompositeChannelBuffer at all. It just gives you some more advanced operations like access directly a component on index x etc.